# Amazon EC2 installing wordpress, page is blank

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install the wordpress on an Amazon EC2 (Following L(Amazon Linux)AMP)
I followed this instruction http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html.
For some reason when I tried loading the public DNS, it is just a blank page.
I even turned on WP_DEBUG to true in the wp config but it is still blank page and I am running out of ideas to debug it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `I tried loading the public DNS` - please explain.

Comment: whenever I typed the root URL (http://mywebsite.com), no message but just blank page.

Comment: Is `mywebsite.com` pointing to an `Elastic IP` in your AWS account **or** the `Public IP` assigned to your instance? Are you aware the public IP for your instance changes every time it is rebooted, stopped & restarted?

Comment: have u checked the instance and internet gateway settings??